# Python: How to write to read and write to a global variable

Tags: python, variables, global, local

Trying to read and write to a global variable from inside an if/else statement but getting an error

> SyntaxError: name 'PREV_HASH' is assigned to before global declaration

I have tried using the global syntax but I can't get it to work. Not used to the global v local variables in python

```py
PREV_HASH = ''
LOGFILE_DIRECTORY = 'c:\\securelog\\securelog_logs\\'
ARCHIVE_FOLDER = 'c:\\securelog\\securelog_archive\\'
WORKFILES_FOLDER = 'c:\\securelog\\securelog_workfiles\\'
TMP_FOLDER = 'c:\\securelog\\processed\\'
COMPLETED_FOLDER = 'c:\\securelog\\completed\\'

CHAIN_FILE = WORKFILES_FOLDER + 'chain_info.txt'



#check if this is the first run, if it is hardcode the block & previous hash and pass the hash 
if chain_list[0] == 1:
    fileHandle = open (CHAIN_FILE, 'r+')
    fileHandle.write('1,0,' + hasher.hexdigest())
    fileHandle.close()
    global PREV_HASH
    PREV_HASH = hasher.hexdigest()
    #print("1 previous hash is: " + str(PREV_HASH))
else:
    #update list with hash of current and previous block
    ###del (chain_list[1:])
    global PREV_HASH
    chain_list.insert (1,PREV_HASH)
    print("2 previous hash is: " + str(PREV_HASH))
    chain_list.insert (2,hasher.hexdigest())
    fileHandle = open (CHAIN_FILE, 'a')
    print('2 what is the chain list at this point:' + str(chain_list))

    #Write the contents of the list to the chain file on a new line and separate with a comma
    fileHandle.write(',' + str(chain_list[2]))
    fileHandle.close()

    PREV_HASH = hasher.hexdigest()
```

I expect on the first run of the script, a new file to be created and contain one line with 1, 0 and a hash key that was generated in a previous step ("hasher.hexdigest()")
That hash will then be saved in a global variable PREV_HASH

Then on the second run the file will be updated with a new line from a list. It will contain an incremented number, previous hash and current hash

> 2,previous #,current #

When removing the global PREV_HASH i get the following output

```
>file does not exist
>-----------------
>24
>1--2019-05-31-archive.zip
>what is the chain list at this point:[1, 0, 0]
>1 previous hash is:

>C:\Python>"SL Proof of Concept.py"
>-----------------
>17
>2--2019-05-31-archive.zip
>what is the chain list at this point:[2, '0', '01d056902f77f5a247f639d363b67827d762d72f9738498989d417563c504a3f82f7b44d7e827cd35843545d33856c85']
>2 previous hash before insert is:
>2 what is the chain list at this point:[2, '', '93fcc831b99a8de59063924a994bf81d09dc677b635e32fc133747ca564bfa843fa6bf60274feeb372a5eeb6f406a120', '0', '01d056902f77f5a247f639d363b67827d762d72f9738
498989d417563c504a3f82f7b44d7e827cd35843545d33856c85']
```

Comment: There is no nested scope here at all. Just get rid of the `global ...` lines.

Comment: There's no need for the `global`. You've already defined it at the top...

Comment: You only need to identify a variable as `global` when you're trying to access it from inside a function.  You don't have any functions here, just top-level code.

Comment: Global variables don't store state *between separate invocations.* You'll need to write the value of that variable to a file and read it back from there, or something like that.

Comment: @JohnGordon: You don't need to define a variable as `global` when you access it from a function. You only need to do it if you try to change the variable from a function.

Comment: Cheers for the help all.. I've removed the "global PREV_HASH" line but for some reason when writing back to the file it's not adding the data from the PREV_HASH variable. Can't figure out what I'm doing wrong

Comment: @Jazmaina If you want to store data between separate invocations, you need to store it in a file yourself.

Comment: @SolomonUcko Ah yeah, I understand now.. Been looking at this for ages and the brain stopped working. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

If this code is at the top level of a file, just remove these `global` statements.

If this code is within something, you need to put `global` before the first assignment, on the first line. (`PREV_HASH = ''`)